# how to access data array data provider yii2?

Tags: php, arrays, yii, yii2, frameworks

i have used ArrayDataProvider in controller yii2.

```html
<?php

public function actionPagination_product2(){
$tb_tab=Tablet::tableName();
Digital.inner_memory')->asArray()->all();
$data = Digital::find()->joinWith('tablet',true,'Left Join')->where('Tablet.sup_id = Digital.id')->asArray()->all();
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
  'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['id'],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);

   return $this->render('pagination_pro2', [
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   ]);
   
   ?>
```

and in view pagination_pro2 i have

```html
<?php
   use yii\widgets\ListView;
   echo ListView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  
      'itemView' => '_page1',
   ]);
?>
```

and in view _page1 i have

```html
<?php
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;
?>
<div class = "user">


   <?php 
foreach($model as $attribute => $value) {
   // do your stuff here
if(isset($model['sim_num'])){
echo "aaaa";
}
}
?>

</div>
```

that works true.but i want to access one by one of model attributes.

are that works true?
what have to do? 
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access model attributes one by one in view `_page1` use `foreach` loop:

1. If your data is just array:

   ```
   foreach($model as $attribute => $value) {
      // do your stuff here
   }
   ```
2. If your array is array of models:

   ```
   foreach($model->attributes as $attribute => $value) {
      // do your stuff here
   }
   ```

Comment: tnx.it has to be work but shows an error as : Trying to get property of non-object in foreach line how to fix it ? thank you

Comment: thank you..that error resolved ;)) just is there any way to access each attribute of each element seperately ? for example like:$model['sim_num'] . how can do that ?

Comment: If your data is just key=>value array, you can access it normally like array: `if(isset($model['sim_num'])) {   // do your stuff on $model['sim_num']); }`

Comment: i have that in array but when use isset not working :((
excuse me to ask a lot :))

Comment: It's okay, i like to fix stuff like this :P Can you update question with code how you use it, and if you can, result of `var_dump($model);die;`?

Comment: ohhhh sorry.it s now save :)

Comment: Can you add result of `var_dump($model);die;` aswell?

Comment: How about `<?=print_r($model)?>` in `_page1` view?

Comment: Showing 1-2 of 2 items.
Array ( [id] => 1 [size] => 2321 [weight] => [inner_memory] => [screen_size] => [screen_type] => [wifi_desc] => [bluetooth] => [batery] => [super_id] => 2 [body_struct] => [process] => [other] => [os] => [gesture] => [items] => [speaker] => [tablet] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 7 [sim_num] => 3 [network] => bad [twog_network] => [threeg_network] => [fourg_network] => [technology] => sad [gps] => sd [gateway_connection] => sda [camera] => 2 [resolusion_camera] => 321 [automatic_focus] => 12312 [camera_flash] => 231 [video] => 21312

Comment: attributes are shown correctly but i can not use one of them :))

Comment: Theres no attribute `sim_num` in your array, theres in subarray `tablet`, which can be accessed by `$model['tablet']['sim_num']`

Comment: that is true.but when i use  $model['tablet']['sim_num'] to echo returns Undefined index: sim_num .

Comment: Its array od arrays, so `$model['tablet'][0]['sim_num']`

Comment: thhhhhank youuuu my friend ;) it disturbes me :))) good luck in every time :))))) i test more in that case and if any question i ask you again :))))
thanks again ;)